# How to create .dmg of a folder from objective-c or terminal?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, terminal

**Scenario**

I need to convert a folder to .dmg using objective-c however, I am not able find any script in obj-c that is why I am looking for a terminal command that can do this.

**Research**

I am using the given below terminal command in order to convert a folder to .dmg

```
hdiutil create -format UDZO -srcfolder 
"/Users/Paxcel/Desktop/IMG" 
"/Users/Paxcel/Desktop/IMG.dmg"
```

**Problem**

The above command is not working and giving no result as shown in the screenshot given below:
[image]

Please suggest a solution that can help me create a .dmg file of a folder. Many thanks for your attention.

P.S: I have to use either obj-c or terminal because I am creating an utility in cocoa app.

Comment: If you don't need to do it from Terminal, I suggest you to use DMG-Creator http://dmgcreator.sourceforge.net/en/

Comment: Thanks for reply @EnriMR but I have to do it from obj-c or terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a stray `"` in your command line.

The `>` prompt means *more please*; the shell wants you to terminate the `"`.

Answer (score 2):

Using **"** was a mistake. I am from windows world and there (in windows) you always have to put a path into quotes **"c://test.txt"**

**Earlier (*Wrong*)**

```
hdiutil create -format UDZO -srcfolder 
"/Users/Paxcel/Desktop/IMG" 
"/Users/Paxcel/Desktop/IMG.dmg"
```

**Correct**

```
hdiutil create -format UDZO -srcfolder 
/Users/Paxcel/Desktop/IMG
/Users/Paxcel/Desktop/IMG.dmg
```

**However if you path contains spaces then if you use quotes then it will give an error like given below**
[image]

**Resolution**
In order to escape the error you must use '\' before spaces ' ' as given below:

```
hdiutil create -format UDZO -srcfolder 
/Users/Paxcel/Desktop/IMG\ for\ design
/Users/Paxcel/Desktop/IMG\ for\ design.dmg
```

**I have run both commands and the result is shown in the screen shot given below**
Quoted path is not working but using '\' in path is working like a charm
[image]

Comment: Also in UNIX it's not a bad idea to wrap paths into (double) quotes. It's even required If the path contains spaces or other special characters.

Comment: @vadian its not true. you will get an error if you will try to do so. I have edited my answer and shown what will happen if you put a path into quotes with its resolution

Comment: Of course you have to write always an opening and closing quote at beginning and end of the path respectively.

Comment: @vadian following command is not working: hdiutil create -format UDZO -srcfolder 
"/Users/Paxcel/Desktop/IMG for design" 
"/Users/Paxcel/Desktop/IMG.dmg for design"

Comment: PS: the correct escaping sequence is either `/Users/Paxcel/Desktop/IMG\ for\ design` or `"/Users/Paxcel/Desktop/IMG for design"`. In your most recent comment you probably mean "/Users/Paxcel/Desktop/IMG for design.dmg"  with `dmg` at the end

Comment: Dear @vadian, I have added a new screenshot in my answer in which I have shown both of your method and only '\' method is working and the other one is not.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the proper double quote character? It must be hex 0x22 dez 34. And there is an error message in the first attempt: *Only one image can be created at a time*

Comment: Of course, I have copied pasted both (working and not working) the commands in the answer and to prove that its happening I have even added a screen shot. @vadian Sir.

Comment: vadian is correct in his assertion about double-quotes.  You can even using single quotes.  It's fairly straight-forward: spaces are used to separate command line arguments and therefore you need to group the words of a single command in quotes or by escaping them.  This has been the case since the 1970s. If you are not seeing this then something else is going wrong with your particular invocation.  EDIT: Having looked at a close-up of your screenshot, you are **not** using double-quote characters; vadian was correct about that as well.